# Синоним слову оккультный

Tags: синонимы

Здравствуйте! Интересует можно ли применить вместо слова скрытный или скрытый синоним "оккультный". Если да, то на основании каких правил, словарей или книг? Спасибо!

Comment: @Павел911, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Нет, слово ''оккультный'' связан с магией, потусторонним миром. В качестве синонима можно привести: кабалистический, эзотерический. Слово же ''скрытный'' никак не связано с магией, потусторонней силой.

Answer (score 2):

Со словом "скрытый" прилагательное ''оккультный'' связано этимологией. "Оккультный" происходит от лат. occultus - «скрытый, сокровенный, тайный».

Оккультный обряд или оккультное учение можно назвать скрытым, тайным в значении "предназначенный только для посвященных или специалистов".

А вот скрытый, тайный не всегда оккультный. Оккультный - сверхъестественный, таинственно связанный с потусторонним миром, необъяснимый посредством законов опыта и положительного знания.

А скрытный - это человек, избегающий откровенности, или его образ жизни - совсем не подходит.

Comment: Спасибо! А если в сочетании - оккультный гепатит, может ли это расцениваться как скрытый гепатит, т.е. невидимый при рутинном обследовании?

Comment: Да,это так.Оккультная инфекция, оккультный гепатит-  скрытая инфекция,скрытый гепатит, который протекает бессимптомно. Д-р Фран Giampietro  ввел термин "инфекции оккультные" в конце 1930-х.  Значит, в данном примере синонимы- скрытый, бессимптомный. Такую инфекцию трудно определить При оккультном гепатите В не выявляются никакие маркеры вируса, но присутствует вирусная ДНК; другим вариантом скрытой инфекции может быть отсутствие детектируемых концентраций HBsAg при наличии антител к HBsAg;  http://dntpasteur.ru/news.php?number=402

Comment: латентный - несколько другое, это скрытый период

Comment: В Большом медицинском словаре оккультного гепатита нет - есть латентный: h. latens - гепатит, протекающий бессимптомно. А инфекция называется скрытой или тоже латентной: i. latens. Ничего оккультного нет. Видимо, это был неудачный перевод или экспериментальное название, не вошедшее в современную терминологию.

Answer (score 1):

Синоним к скрытому гепатиту - латентный.

См. Большой толковый словарь:

ЛАТЕНТНЫЙ [тэ], -ая, -ое; -тен, -тна, -тно. [от лат. latens (latentis) - скрытый, невидимый] Спец. Внешне не проявляющийся, скрытный. *Л. период болезни*.

Comment: @tat, абсолютно согласен. Оккультный связан с мистикой, эзотерикой. С тем, что окутано тайной. Поэтому называть гепатит оккультным  - неверно. Это, скорее всего, неудачный перевод с латинского.

Answer (score 0):

Эзотерический. "Каб(б)алистический" вносит таки нежелательный нац. оттенок (ну, Мадонна, ну что с неё возьмёшь). Если хотите полное импортозамещение - просто "тайный". или даже сОкрытый (произносить с оканьем :)